# cannot resolve method 'findViewById(int)' for my webview

Tags: android, webview

I am getting error  cannot **resolve method 'findViewById(int)'** when 
   call the webview ,how to solve this? [image]
   actually this webview is for my home fragment( 1st fragment of the program)

```
package com.fb.jaisonjoseph.facebookbasic;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.webkit.WebView;



 /**
   * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class Home_Fragment extends Fragment {

public WebView mwebView;
public Home_Fragment() {

    // Required empty public constructor
}



@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment



    WebView view=(WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    view.loadUrl("http://google.com");
    view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    view.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());




    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home_, container, false);
}

}
```

Comment: you have to inflate layout in view and use view.findViewById

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this way.

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home_, null);
        WebView view=(WebView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.webView);
        view.loadUrl("http://google.com");
        view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        view.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
        return rootView;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Issues

1.)  You are returning a new view everytime

```
return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home_, container, false);
```

2.) Use the inflated view to find your views

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view =inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home_, container, false);
    //   ^^^ will have all view of fragment_home_ layout

    WebView webView = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.webView);
    //                         ^^^^ use view to find your webview

    webView.loadUrl("http://google.com");
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
    return view;
}
```

**Note :** you can remove you `mwebView` from `Home_fragmnet` class but if you want to use your webview in other methods then use `mwebView` instead of the local `WebView view` variable

```
 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view =inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home_, container, false);
    //   ^^^ will have all view of fragment_home_ layout

    mwebView = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.webView);
    //^^^ use global variable instead of creating a local one

    mwebView.loadUrl("http://google.com");
    mwebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mwebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
    return view;
}
```

Comment: How do you resolve first Issue you pointed out? I have always been returning inflated view.

Comment: @rupinderjeet by new View ,i mean  nothing is initialized inside that view , the OP has to initialize the view inside the view returned by the inflater otherwise nothing will work ,if someone wants to persist the fragment then use [fragmentManager](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use this line of Code:

```
WebView view=(WebView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.webView);
```

instead of

```
WebView view=(WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
```

This is becauce `findViewById()` can't be invoked on a `Fragment` directly. You either have to refere to the Acticity or call it on a `View`-object

Comment: findViewById() can be invoked on a fragment directly.

Comment: I am pretty sure it can't, but you are welcome to prove me otherwise :)

Comment: Yeah, it has to be invoked on a View.